# PHP header redirect is reloading the same part on the HTML page as opposed to another part on the HTML page using ids

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm making a website that involves PHP redirects, but when I redirect with the header function it doesn't redirect to the right id it just redirects to the page without the id.

It is supposed to redirect to:

```
header('Location: '.$findHttp.'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php#redirect');
```

But it actually redirects to:

```
header('Location: '.$findHttp.'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php');
```

Can you please tell me why that is?

Here is the full PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['reportsubmit'])) {
    $radio = $_POST['customer'];
    if ($radio == 'customer') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#customer">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'item') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#item">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'department') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#department">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    } else if ($radio == 'person') {
        $redirect = 'Click <a href="#person">here</a> to continue on with the form';
    }
    $findHttp = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http';
    header('Location: '.$findHttp.'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php#redirect');
    exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['customersubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['itemsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['departmentsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['personsubmit'])) {
    //process form
    //redirect
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: What browser are you testing with? I can redirect to URLs with anchor-fragments (`http://example.com/#anchor`) in Firefox and Opera and Chrome...

Comment: I'm using Opera currently. I can go to pages that use anchor-fragments if I just type in the URL with the anchor-fragment, but when I use it with the PHP header method it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to work with GET function?
Like that.

```
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php?id=redirect');
```